# About the interface Cloneable

Tags: java

For example, we write the class XXX to implement the Cloneable, and we override the method clone in the class XXX, is it necessary to invoke super.clone in the method?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of important pointers

1. Cloneable is a marker interface. Marker interface does not have methods or variables declared. They just tell the JVM that this class has a capability of doing something for example cloneable, serializable etc
2. When you are saying super.clone, you are not invoking a method from cloneable, you are actually invoking clone() method of super class or by default Object.clone();

If you do not want an implementation of your own, you can use Object's clone method, but that will give you a shallow copy of your object. If you want to do something more than that, it is better to give your own implementation.

And regarding your original question, no it is not a compulsion to call a super method if you know your code is handling everything. But if you need to use functionality from a super class (in this case Object class), you should call super method

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you don't call the super class implementation, any data it needs won't be copied to the new clone.

**UPDATE**
For example, super class may want to copy it's private variables to the new clone.

Actual implementation should be

```
XXX clone =    super.clone();

// 'clone' now has all the data the super class wants to know.
// add any details from your XXX class to it here.

return clone;
```

Comment: if i first call the construct of XXX, does that matter or any bad influence?

Comment: Using the return value from `super.clone();` is recommended. Otherwise you'll risk losing any data that's needed by your super class. If the super class os `Object` , there is no loss, but it's good practise to use `super.clone();`.

Answer (score 0):

*edit 
ok i was wrong
here is what super.clone() calls:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29

you should call super.clone()

Comment: Java 1.4 is now more than ten years old. Please consider linking to javadocs for a more recent version of Java. (Now, why Google seems to hugely favorize javadocs for Java 1.4.2 when you perform a search is something i've asked myself for quite some time by now.)

Comment: @Buhb the answer is that not only Google looks for the more updated information regarding your search, but it also factors "old & good" results in a higher rank. It makes sense with many things (a cooking web-site for example) but not all the time... :)

Comment: @Buhb You're right, it's annoying. Those javadocs are seriously out-of-date and most people miss the fact that they landed on a very old page. What I do to avoid this is always search a class like this: `java se 7 integer` . This way, I get the javadoc for java 7. I did this for so long now, it has become a reflex, I do it automatically :) .

Comment: @SoboLAN: Yes, that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If `we override the method clone in the class XXX` - NO call to super is needed. You just do there what you want. - means copy what and how you like it to be copied.